# How to install software & addons in the Ubuntu Software Store correctly?

Tags: software-center

My questions is, "I want to install a program from the Ubuntu Software Store. I want to install the software "MonoDevelop". I want to have the add-ons, except for the .net server ones, there is two. I want the rest of them. How do I install it correctly without errors, like no added addons. I want them added. Would I have to install the program with out the add-ons first or do I have to click all the add-ons and then click apply and then install the program, or what is your plan of action toward doing this correct? Thank You.
Sincerely
Ronnie Marlow

Answer (score 2):

Go to USC search for MonoDevelop, check all the add on that you want, and then click on the install button.  This will install the application with the add ons.

[image]